# timediff() limitado até 838:59:59, como resolver?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

SGBD: MYSQL

Problema: Estou somando HORAS em um tipo de campo TIME e o resultado esperado está acima de 838:59:59, mas está visível somente até este limite. Como resolver?

```
SELECT      he.empresa,
            SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN timediff(hr.hora_final,hr.hora_inicial) < 0 THEN TIMEDIFF(CONCAT('1990-01-02', ' ',hr.hora_final),CONCAT('1990-01-01', ' ',hr.hora_inicial)) ELSE timediff(hr.hora_final,hr.hora_inicial) END))) AS Soma
FROM        hora_extra AS he
INNER JOIN  horario_extra AS hr ON hr.codigo = he.cod_extra
WHERE       he.empresa = 1
ORDER BY    he.empresa;
```

Resultado:

```
1|838:59:59|
```

Comment: Não seria o caso de simplesmente usar `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` ?https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff Explique com mais detalhes seu objetivo (se precisa do resultado em minutos, segundos, como vai usá-lo, etc), que talvez tenhamos como ajudar melhor.

Comment: O resultado esperado é em hh:mm:ss. Nada complicado, só precisava das horas somadas. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quando a função [**SEC_TO_TIME**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time)() é usada o valor retornado é do tipo [**TIME**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html), e as restrições para esse tipo de dado são aplicadas (Mínimo: '-838:59:59' e máximo: '838:59:59').

Como no seu caso há possibilidade de retornar um valor além do limite, uma maneira é converter hora, minuto e segundo separadamente.

Criei a função abaixo, ai fica bem mais fácil de usar nas queries.

```
DELIMITER //                                                                              

CREATE FUNCTION SEC_TO_TIMEB (in_seconds bigint) RETURNS VARCHAR(15)                                                                                                           
BEGIN                                                                                     
    DECLARE hours VARCHAR(9);                                                 
    DECLARE minutes CHAR(2);                                               
    DECLARE seconds CHAR(2);                                               

    SET hours   := FLOOR(in_seconds / 3600);                                              
    SET hours   := IF(hours < 10,CONCAT('0',hours),hours);                                

    SET minutes := FLOOR(MOD(in_seconds,3600) / 60);                                      
    SET minutes := IF(minutes < 10,CONCAT('0',minutes),minutes);                          

    SET seconds := MOD(MOD(in_seconds,3600),60);                                          
    SET seconds := IF(seconds < 10,CONCAT('0',seconds),seconds);

    RETURN CONCAT(hours,':',minutes,':',seconds);                                         
END //                                                                                    

DELIMITER ;
```

Dessa maneira basta usar a nova função na sua query.

```
SELECT      he.empresa,
            SEC_TO_TIMEB(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN timediff(hr.hora_final,hr.hora_inicial) < 0 THEN TIMEDIFF(CONCAT('1990-01-02', ' ',hr.hora_final),CONCAT('1990-01-01', ' ',hr.hora_inicial)) ELSE timediff(hr.hora_final,hr.hora_inicial) END))) AS Soma
FROM        hora_extra AS he
INNER JOIN  horario_extra AS hr ON hr.codigo = he.cod_extra
WHERE       he.empresa = 1
ORDER BY    he.empresa;
```

Imagino que haja soluções que sejam mais otimizadas, mas creio que não haja outra maneira de realizar o calculo com o TIME sem separar os campos. Se alguém tiver outra maneira de realizar a conversão, ficarei de olho nesse tópico. :)

Comment: Excelente! Solução perfeita!

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um bug do MySQL, nesse link aqui você encontra informações sobre esse bug e uma função para resolver esse problema [bugs.mysql.com](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=29381)

Essa função retornará H:m, não sei qual o formato que necessita, mas se precisar pegar os segundos substitua o return por:

`RETURN CONCAT( HOUR, ':', MINUTES, ':', LPAD(MOD(SECS,60),2, '0'));`

Comment: Na verdade não é um bug, é uma limitação do próprio campo TIME que armazena somente 3 bytes. É a mesma coisa que tentar adicionar um valor maior que 16777215 em um campo MEDIUMINT.